# Sequence: Uniformly bounded vs. bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(x^{k}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a sequence such that

$$
x^{k} \to x \qquad \text{for } k \to \infty
$$

for a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Assume that there is a $M>0$ and a $l>0$ with

$$
\| x^{k}\| \leq M \qquad \text{for all } k \geq l\,.
$$

---

**Question: Is this sequence $(x^{k})$ then called *uniformly bounded* or just *bounded*?**

Comment: It is  a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: Also: note that you don't have to assume the existence of such an $M$. Convergent sequences are automatically bounded.

Comment: Take a closer look at the definition of uniformly bounded and see if you can see why it doesn't apply to sequences directly.  Uniform boundedness is a property of functions (or families of functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of *uniform boundedness* does not apply to sequences of elements of $\mathbb R^n$. Such sequences are bounded if $\| x^{k}\| \leq M $ for all $k$.

However, it applies to sequences of *functions* $f_n : X \to \mathbb R^n$. A function $f : X \to \mathbb R^n$ is called *bounded* if $\| f(x)\| \leq M $ for all $x \in X$. A sequence of functions $f_n$ is called *uniformly bounded* if  $\| f_n(x)\| \leq M $ for all $x \in X$ and all $n$. Note that in this case all $f_n$ are bounded. The sequence of constant functions $c_n(x) = n$ is not uniformly bounded although each $f_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Many thanks for all your quick responses and explainations! <3